# Eclipse CDT Custom Debugger

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I would like to extend the debugger of eclipse cdt so that it is able to skip lines with a specified line number by default (step).

I was wondering what could be extended to do so, because I don't need to write a complete new debugger, the c/c++ functionallity is as good as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, so I provide some starting points for you so you can narrow down your question a bit.

### DSF-GDB

The C/C++ Debugger in Eclipse is provided by CDT's DSF (Debug Services Framework). DSF is an amazing, but complicated asynchronous framework to write debuggers in. DSF-GDB is the implementation of DSF for GDB debuggers.

1. I recommend starting with the [DSF Tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dsf/intro/dsf_programming_intro.html?cp=14_0_5)
2. Try to use the DSF-GDB custom extended example plug-in [org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf.gdb](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf-gdb/org.eclipse.cdt.examples.dsf.gdb)
3. Have a look at [How to extend DSF-GDB](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/cdt-debug-dsf-gdb-extensibility)
4. If you have specific lines in C code, you will need to be aware and make your users aware of the limitations regarding compiler optimizations. e.g. if you write:

```c
int x = 2
x++;
x++;
```

and expect to be able to run line 1 and 3 and skip 2, then you are going to have to get involved with the compiler, not just the debugger as the compiler will normally optimize the above to essentially `int x = 4`.

### CDI Debugger

The [CDI Debugger](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_debug_core_CDebugger.html), aka the older pre-DSF CDT debugger is expected to be removed in CDT 9.0 scheduled for release in June 2016. The CDI Debugger is associated with the `org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.CDebugger` extension point. See the message from the CDT co-leads [Marc](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg29348.html) and [Doug](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg29310.html) and the [wiki entry](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/planning/9.0). Therefore do not base new development work on CDI.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks for your information and effort. Will have a deeper look into next week. The cdt extension point CDebugger is no direction to go then?

Comment: I am not sure where to extend in examples.dsf.gdb example?

Comment: Only method calls should be skipped, and only visually

Comment: There is a patch I recently contributed https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/61534/ that shows exactly what you need to do to add a new command to DSF. It is not merged yet, but the diffs should show you what needs to be added to a DSF session to add new functionality.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to do something (broadly) similar to Run To Line and/or Resume At Line. I suspect with your additional custom logic, plus the contents of the implementations of the existing commands in DSF you should be able to achieve what you are looking for? See ResumeAtLine, RunToLine and MoveToLine in http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/dsf/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/debug/internal/ui/actions/

Comment: If the actions can be overriden there then yes, I don't want to add new stuff, just customize the existing one.

Comment: actions can be overridden, the example plug-in in git master shows how to override Terminate (to add a confirmation prompt), and my patch shows how to add a whole new command (uselessly, but simply, showing Gdb Version)

Comment: Do you know what AdapterType is used in createModelAdapter for your mentioned RunToLine, ResumeAtLine, ... actions or did you meant other actions like DsfStepIntoCommand, DsfStepOverCommand, ...

Comment: found the point, i think SuspendResumeAdapterFactory and RetargettableActionAdapterFactory

Comment: Do you think it's the right way to create one of this factories?

Comment: Not one of these factories persay, but you may be able to extend/reuse one of them. i.e. you will need a factory (or add into one of the existing factories) a new adaptation. note that these two factories you mentioned are there to adapt specific things (vmcontext and disassembly part), there is also the overarching adapter factory GdbAdapterFactory that needs consideration too.

Comment: I have just seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175729/eclipse-cdt-extend-adapterfactory, not sure why I missed it. I'll have a read and get back to you.