# Eclipse CDT extend AdapterFactory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I try to override the functionality of CDT ResumeAtLine, MoveToLine, RunToLine. For this reason I created a custom SuspendResumeAdapterFactory but it isn't loaded but compiles and runs without error. Do I maybe need a custom adaptableType too?

Here is the content of my `plugin.xml`.

```xml
  <extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.adapters">
      <factory 
            class="my.package.CustomSuspendResumeAdapterFactory" 
            adaptableType="org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui.viewmodel.IVMContext">
         <adapter type="org.eclipse.debug.core.model.ISuspendResume"/>
      </factory>
   </extension>
```

And here my `CustomSuspendResumeAdapterFactory` this class is reconstructed from memory not 100% sure if the syntax is correct, but I think it should be clear to see what I want to do.

```java
package my.package;

import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.datamodel.DMContexts;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.actions.MoveToLine;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.actions.ResumeAtLine;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.actions.RunToLine;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.IRunControl.IContainerDMContext;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.IRunControl.IExecutionDMContext;
import org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui.viewmodel.datamodel.IDMVMContext;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdapterFactory;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.model.ISuspendResume;

public class CustomSuspendResumeAdapterFactory implements IAdapterFactory {

    static class SuspendResume implements ISuspendResume, IAdaptable {

        private final CustomRunToLine fRunToLine;
        private final CustomMoveToLine fMoveToLine;
        private final CustomResumeAtLine fResumeAtLine;

        SuspendResume(IExecutionDMContext execCtx) {
            fRunToLine = new CustomRunToLine(execCtx);
            fMoveToLine = new CustomMoveToLine(execCtx);
            fResumeAtLine = new CustomResumeAtLine(execCtx);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public <T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter) {
            if (adapter.isInstance(RunToLine.class)) {
                System.out.println("CUSTOM RUNTOLINE");
                return (T)fRunToLine;
            }
            if (adapter.isInstance(MoveToLine.class)) {
                System.out.println("CUSTOM MOVETOLINE");
                return (T)fMoveToLine;
            }
            if (adapter.isInstance(ResumeToLine.class)) {
                System.out.println("CUSTOM RESUMEATLINE");
                return (T)fResumeAtLine;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canResume() { return false; }
        @Override
        public boolean canSuspend() { return false; }
        // This must return true because the platform
        // RunToLineActionDelegate will only enable the
        // action if we are suspended
        @Override
        public boolean isSuspended() { return true; }
        @Override
        public void resume() throws DebugException {}
        @Override
        public void suspend() throws DebugException {}
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T getAdapter(Object adaptableObject, Class<T> adapterType) {
        if (ISuspendResume.class.equals(adapterType)) {
            if (adaptableObject instanceof IDMVMContext) {
                IExecutionDMContext execDmc = DMContexts.getAncestorOfType(
                    ((IDMVMContext)adaptableObject).getDMContext(),
                    IExecutionDMContext.class);
                // It only makes sense to RunToLine, MoveToLine or
                // ResumeAtLine if we are dealing with a thread, not a container
                if (execDmc != null && !(execDmc instanceof IContainerDMContext)) {
                    return (T)new SuspendResume(execDmc);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?>[] getAdapterList() {
        return new Class[] { ISuspendResume.class };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why your code is not run

You have provided a new adapter factory that converts object types that are already handled. i.e. your plugin.xml says you can convert `IVMContext` to `ISuspendResume`. But the DSF plug-in already provides such an adapter factory. If you have a new target type (like IMySpecialRunToLine) you could install a factory for that, it would take `IVMContext` and convert it to a `IMySpecialRunToLine`).

Although dated, the [Eclipse Corner Article on Adapter Pattern](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Adapters/index.html) may be useful if this is a new concept.

### How to do custom Run To Line implementation

If you want to provide different implementation of *Run To Line*, you need to provide your own version of `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.IRunControl2.runToLine(IExecutionDMContext, String, int, boolean, RequestMonitor)`. The `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.internal.ui.actions.RunToLine` class is simply glue to connect UI features (such as buttons/etc some provided directly, some by the core eclipse debug) to the DSF backend. i.e. if you look at what `RunToLine` does, all it actually does is get the `IRunControl2` service and call `runToLine` on it.

The way to provider your own implementation of `IRunControl2` is override `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.service.GdbDebugServicesFactory.createRunControlService(DsfSession)` and provide your own `GdbDebugServicesFactory` in your custom launch delegate by overriding `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.launching.GdbLaunchDelegate.newServiceFactory(ILaunchConfiguration, String)`

`RunToLine` will be triggered when the user select *Run To Line* from the popup menu in the editor, as per this screenshot:

[image: runtoline]

Comment: When is a "runToLine" triggered? Managed to create CustomGDBRunControl extends GDBRunControl, but neither the usual MIRunControl.runToLine is called nor my custom one :-/ I thought it would be triggered after a "step into" command?

Comment: step into and run to line are two distinct things, step into is handled by `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.IRunControl.step(IExecutionDMContext, StepType, RequestMonitor)` with a step type of `STEP_INTO`

Comment: But in IRunControl.step it is not possible to determine the line-number of an instruction?

Comment: I would like that a click on step-into will skip a line with a line number. So I define some linenumbers exp. 1,2,3,4 and every step into that would lead into line numbers 1,2,3,4 would be replaced by a step over.

Comment: When you are in the "step" command, you can do *whatever* you like. In particular you can ask the debugger what line number you are on and then decide to issue step into or step over at that point.

Comment: Note, what you are describing here sounds a little like step filtering (that JDT has). GDB does have support for it, but I don't think anyone has written support for the GDB feature in Eclipse: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97675/discussion-between-jonah-graham-and-stefan-sprenger).